# How to move RadioGroup below specified EditText Android Dev

Tags: android, xml, calculator, android-relativelayout

I'm learning Android App Dev. My problem is that the radioButtons are on my editText1 and editText2. I dreamed about this order:

1. editText with first number
2. editText with second number
3. radio button +
4. radio button -
5. radio button *
6. radio button /
7. textView Result
8. BUTTON

where (i+1)-th element is below i-th element.

I'm wondering what should I do, because when I add `android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"` to the radioGroup it does not anything.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.addme.calculator.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="first number"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:hint="second number"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup">
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioPlus"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="+" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioPlus"
                android:id="@+id/radioMinus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMult"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioMinus"
                android:text="*" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioDiv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="/"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioMult"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:text="Button"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:text="Result" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: use `android:layout_below`

Answer (score 1):

in your layout xml this property `android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"` is outside radio group tag. Check it

Comment: Thanks, it was a dumb mistake. Everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your xml in radio group at line:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
```

change it to like below:

```
    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText2">
```

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" is outside radio group tag. change your code with below code

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="first number"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:hint="second number"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioPlus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="+" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMinus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioPlus"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioMinus"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioDiv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioMult"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="Button"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:text="Result" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, radioButtons auto align in the RadioGroup

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="+" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioDiv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using RelativeLayout? You can use a LinearLayout(Vertical) as a container of all the views. It is the easiest method.